# How do I use a Singleton instance in other classes

Tags: java, javafx, singleton

I'm using the Singleton pattern below to create a user so that my program will be aware that a user is logged in. I'm trying to show the username in different pages of my JavaFx program so I want to use the username details from the instance in multiple classes. When I try to use `Usersession.toString`, it says that a non-static method cannot be used in a static context. How do I fix this?

```
public final class UserSession {

    private static UserSession instance;

    private String userName;


    private UserSession(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public static UserSession getInstace(String userName) {
        if(instance == null) {
            instance = new UserSession(userName);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void cleanUserSession() {
        userName = "";// or null

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UserSession{" +
                "userName='" + userName + "}";
    }
}
```

Comment: you can't change `toString()` to static so create a new method

Comment: That's suboptimal design right there. Instead of making the singleton only ever be initialized by passing a parameter leave the parameter out and allow to set the property later via non-static setter. If you want to make `UserSession` a immutable type, it would be better to make a different class the singleton, e.g. `SessionHolder` which may or may not contain a session. If you can you should avoid `static` (and in consequence the singleton pattern) though , if you can.

Comment: You should have normal get/set methods for `userName` and no parameter in the getInstance method.

Comment: You can do `UserSession.getInstance("User").toString()`. But note that your design is flawed, as is already pointed out. If you do `UserSession.getInstance("User 1")`, then later call, for example, `UserSession.getInstance("User 2").toString()`, it will return `"UserSession{ userName= User 1}"`, which is unlikely to be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you trying to access method without its instance .
Right way to do it as below:

UserSession.getInstace("your username details").toString();

then it will return below details as per your toString() method:
UserSession{userName='your username details}